# Reference for a book on EM explaining sources, surface currents etc. in Magnetostatics

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations

I am involved in a research project in Magnetostatics. I am a Mathematician, but I did take EM for Electrical Engineers during my Electrical Engineering years. Lately though, my research collaborator has been talking about sources and surface currents in Magnetostatics, and I have questions since I have not studied them before.

We are interested in linear materials, in which $B = \mu H$. I would like to kindly ask for a reference, or a few references, where the Mathematics is explained very clearly, all the while providing some physical intuition as well, for the following concepts: sources, surface currents and boundary matching problems (for example if you have $2$ different media with different magnetic properties, such as a linear material in the air).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Introduction to Electrodynamics by David Griffiths : https://libgen.lc/ads.php?md5=090457f1eb5d2d87c7b80680987c587f
and its solution manual which contains the solutions to a variety of problems in the exercises that might be of your concern : http://93.174.95.29/main/D4FFE7AE2DA687D13B46A7A611C7807C
Griffiths' book is the best book to learn not only magnetostatics but electrostatics and electrodynamics as well for the first time.

2) Classical Electrodynamics by J.D. Jackson : https://libgen.lc/ads.php?md5=3de4d6553073913190333da6e44ac971

3) A lecture notes on magnetostatics by David Tong : https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/em/el2.pdf

Besides, there are many a book on the subject of Magnetostatics itself; someone might mention a few names for you in their answers. As far as I know, the books I mentioned above might be of quite a help for you.

Comment: ++ for Jackson and Griffiths :-)